# How to edit my code with this instructions

Tags: c#

Well I have this requirements :

- Student class
- 3 properties in the Student class
- 2 methods in the Student class
- 3 instances (objects) of the Student class

I did properties, class, objects and i dont get it what I should do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test2
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string name;
        public string lastname;
        static int grade;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Lastname
        {
            get { return lastname; }
            set { lastname = value; }

        }
        public int Grade
        {
            get { return grade; }
            set { grade = value; }
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student a = new Student();
            a.Name = "John";
            a.Lastname = "Park";
            a.Grade = 20;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Lastname: {1} | Grade: {2}", a.Name,a.Lastname, a.Grade);

            Student b = new Student();
            b.Name = "Joe";
            b.Lastname = "Doe";
            b.Grade = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Lastname: {1} | Grade: {2}", b.Name, b.Lastname, b.Grade);

            Student c = new Student();
            c.Name = "Rose";
            c.Lastname = "Hancook";
            c.Grade = 7;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Lastname: {1} | Grade: {2}", c.Name, c.Lastname, c.Grade);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Yes I think i only need methods but im not sure

Comment: You are indeed missing two methods in the `Student` class. But what are those methods *supposed to do*? This are not good requirements.

Comment: I just need to follow the instructions, i think to print  Name,Username,Grade.... not sure tho

Comment: If you aren't told specifically what these methods are supposed to do, have some fun exploring what methods you might be able to come up with using the properties that `Student` has. You might make a method that returns the full name (first + last together as one string). Or perhaps one that returns the full report, first + last + grade (then in your WriteLine calls you can just call the method!)

Comment: *"not sure tho"* - that's why they're not good requirements.

Comment: I cant do anything about it, I really need to figure this out

Comment: Your fields `grade`, `name`, and `lastname` should be `private`, not public or unspecified (which means internal). `grade` should not be static. This is stuff your teacher should, and likely will, ding you for.

Comment: I dont have a teacher :(

Comment: So where did you get the instructions?

Comment: Also if I do that private the objects will show error

Comment: I got it from someone helping me to learn, he is a grown up , he said he wont teach me, just guide me

Comment: No. He's not helping you learn if that's his attitude.

Comment: Well he is an expert, he is about to start his own company so I can complain, plz help

Comment: Well, it's been confirmed that you need to write two methods in your `Student` class, try something and see how it goes. Break the problem down. Start with just one.

Comment: I tried but i shows errors

Comment: I don't see where you'd get any errors making the fields `name` and `lastname` `private`. Note that @EdPlunkett was not talking about the properties `Name` and `Lastname`. They were talking about `public string name` and `public string lastname`. I'm afraid this seems like a poor assignment. You could technically add two methods that literally do nothing and meet the requirements.

Comment: What did you try, and what errors did you get? Update your question with that information.

Comment: yes I didnt get errors this time, i changed the wrong thing

Comment: This is why you need a *teacher*. Being an expert and being a good teacher / tutor / mentor / "guider" are completely unrelated. In the end, he may be doing you more harm than good. Among other things, a good teacher would give you the tools you need to accomplish the assignment.

Comment: @Extraordinary, madreflection still makes a good point. I just handed you the answer. But if you really want to LEARN, you are going to need to more than just copy and paste my code.  You are going to need to make sure that you understand exactly why and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'helper' maybe starting his own company, but clearly he's not a great teacher. The other long answer is a great answer, and here's also a similar answer with broken down explanations to get you started. After this, I suggest you try to find a `C#` course online (there's a ton of free resources out there) and follow along step by step, so you learn the basics.

OK, so now let's take a look at your class. The properties look fine, but they can be improved. You have something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    // More stuff...
}
```

Above, the `private` member variable `firstName` (I took the liberty of changing 'name' to 'firstName' as it was bothering me to no end that the other one is 'lastName' but this is merely 'name'. Sorry.) can only be accessed within the class, while the `Property` associated with it, `FirstName` is `public` and can be accessed from outside the class. As you can see, it 'gets' and 'sets' the value of the member variable `firstName`. So, this can be simplified by eliminating the private member variable completely and using getter/setter properties like as follows. It makes for simpler/cleaner code.

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

So let's redo your `Student` class like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you're required to write two methods, but it doesn't say what they're supposed to say. So let's think about two *useful* methods we can write. As you suggested, a method to print the student's information is indeed a great idea. So let's do that:

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }

    public void PrintStudentInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0} | Last Name: {1} | Grade: {2}", FirstName, Lastname, Grade);
    }
}
```

Now, instead of writing the line of code to print every time you want to print student info, you can simply call this method. To do so, note that you have to make it `public` so that it's accessible from outside. You can write a simple `Main` program and call it like so:

```
static void Main()
{
    Student student1 = new Student
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        Lastname = "Park",
        Grade = 60
    };
    Student student2 = new Student
    {
        FirstName = "Joe",
        Lastname = "Doe",
        Grade = 80
    };
    Student student3 = new Student
    {
        FirstName = "Rose",
        Lastname = "Hancook",
        Grade = 90
    };

    student1.PrintStudentInfo();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that above the way instances of the class `Student` is created is a little different to the way you do, but it accomplishes the same thing.

So what else can we do? Maybe we can have another method to which we pass a 'cutoff' or 'pass' mark, and if the student's grade is greater than or equal to the cutoff, the student passed, otherwise, failed. We want this method to decide if the student passed or failed, and then print a message to indicate the result.

We could then write a method like this, and notice how we make use of the parameter.

```
public void DidStudentPass(int passMark)
{
    if (Grade >= passMark)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} passed with a Grade of {2}.", FirstName, Lastname, Grade);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} failed with a Grade of {2}.", FirstName, Lastname, Grade);
    }
}
```

So, hope this helps. Welcome to the world of programming and good luck. As I said, try to find some resources and keep writing code.

Answer (score 4):

Hey there Extraordinary!

I've taken the liberty of modernizing your code, and also adding some methods so that your requirement is met.

```
using System;

namespace test2
{

    class Program
    {

        public class Student
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
            public int Grade { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student studentA = CreateStudent("John", "Park", 20);
            PrintStudent(studentA);

            Student studentB = CreateStudent("Joe", "Dor", 10);
            PrintStudent(studentB);

            Student studentC = CreateStudent("Rose", "Hancook", 7);
            PrintStudent(studentC);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Student CreateStudent(string name, string lastName, int grade)
        {
            Student student = new Student
            {
                Name = name,
                Lastname = lastName,
                Grade = grade
            };
            return student;
        }

        private static void PrintStudent(Student student)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {student.Name} | Lastname: {student.Lastname} | Grade: {student.Grade}");
        }
    }
}
```

Let's review.

In your class `Student` you can use auto getters and setters.  Makes for way less code!

You now have two methods:

- CreateStudent()
- PrintStudent()

`CreateStudent` takes the details of each student as parameters, builds a new `Student` object, and then sends it back.

`PrintStudent()` just does the simple task of writing the student to the screen.

Note that we don't need the old way of building a string:

```
"Name: {0} | Lastname: {1} | Grade: {2}", c.Name, c.Lastname, c.Grade
```

This is much cleaner:

```
$"Name: {student.Name} | Lastname: {student.Lastname} | Grade: {student.Grade}"
```

The overall advantage of breaking tasks out into smaller methods is that your `Main` method is now super easy to read.  Very clean!

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

This a much better, cleaner, more Object-Oriented approach.

```
using System;

namespace test2
{

    public class Student
    {
        public Student(string name, string lastName, int grade)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Lastname = lastName;
            this.Grade = grade;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public int Grade { get; set; }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {this.Name} | Lastname: {this.Lastname} | Grade: {this.Grade}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student studentA = new Student("John", "Park", 20);
            studentA.Print();

            Student studentB = new Student("Joe", "Dor", 10);
            studentB.Print();

            Student studentC = new Student("Rose", "Hancook", 7);
            studentC.Print();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Again, let's review.

If, as JoshuaRobinson pointed out, the methods need to be inside of the `Student` class, then this will meet that requirement.

the class 'Student' now has a method called a `Constructor`, which means it has the same name as the class itself.

```
        public Student(string name, string lastName, int grade)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Lastname = lastName;
            this.Grade = grade;
        }
```

This will be called anytime you do a `new Student()` and it takes the names and the grade.  It then creates a new `Student`.

The `Print()` method has also been moved into the `Student` class, so it no longer needs to accept a student as a parameter.

Comment: OMG thank you some much <3

Comment: The requirements, such as they are, state: `2 methods in the Student class`. I mean, I assume that means members of `Student`. `CreateStudent` and `PrintStudent` are not members of the `Student` class.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson, ah. I missed that. I will modify

Comment: I didn't notice that because somehow `Student` is now nested in `Program`. Why is that?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson, see the second version in my answer.

Comment: @Extraordinary, the second version in my answer is really a lot better than my first, and actually meets your requirement.

Comment: Can I use the inner class in this ? If yes can you give me an example, i want to learn how

Comment: @Extraordinary, I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Add some get accessors like so:

```
public string GetName(){ if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) { return Name; } else { return "Name not found!"; } }
public bool GradeAboveB() { if (Grade > 80) { return true;} else { return false; } }
```

Comment: How do you think the second method would change if you changed it to `public bool GradeAboveB() { return Grade > 80; }`?